# Redshift skip the first character of split_part()

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table column like below:

```
| cloumn_a           |
| ------------------ |
| Alpha_Black_1      |
| Alpha_Black_2323   |
| Alpha_Red_100      |
| Alpha_Blue_2344    |
| Alpha_Orange_33333 |
| Alpha_White_2      |
|                    |
```

Usually, when I want to split with any symbol or character I am using the `split_part(text, text, integer)` so `split_part(column_a, '_', 1)`

I need to remove the numeric part of each variable and keep only the text part like `Alpha_Black`.

I cannot use the trim function because the numeric part can change

How can I skip the first underscore and split from the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT
    column_a,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(column_a, '_\\d+$', '') AS column_a_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: @Axis No...you misunderstood that.  I think you have to wait at least _ten_ minutes from the time you first post.  This is to give enough people a chance to answer, to avoid people hastily accepting an answer.  When you saw the warning of 1 minute, it was probably already 9 minutes after you first posted.